# run laravel downloaded project on local machine

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to install an `Laravel` Framework project run on my local machine.

- `Laravel` Framework-4 already installed
- Package downloaded - https://github.com/mrakodol/Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site
- now I get error when I try to compose

[image: error]

Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php):

> Windows users must include the bundled php_fileinfo.dll DLL file in php.ini to enable this extension.

Check your php.ini file to ensure the .dll file is listed. The line is probably there and looks like `;extension=php_fileinfo.dll` so just remove the `;`.

Comment: still there is problem, http://localhost/Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site-master/public/ show `Whoops, looks like something went wrong`.

Answer (score 2):

just remove ; before ;extension=php_fileinfo.dll, because ; is used for comment.Many things has default value in php.ini file, the further you go you can customize the php.ini file according to you.